# How to add a text inside rectangle?

Tags: python, pygame

I defined the class of the objects `fences` as follows:

```
class GeoFence(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, rect, risk_level, *groups):
        self._layer = 1
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, groups)
        self.image = pygame.surface.Surface((rect.width, rect.height))
        self.image.fill(GREEN)
        self.rect = rect
        self.risk_level = risk_level
        self.font = pygame.font.SysFont('Arial', 25)
        screen.blit(self.font.render(risk_level, True, (255,0,0)), (200, 100))
```

Each object `fence` is a green rectangle. I want to display a text inside this rectangle. The text is defined by a string `risk_level` that is selected randomly from the list `risks`.

```
all_sprites = pygame.sprite.LayeredUpdates()
fences = pygame.sprite.Group()

risks = ["HIGH","MEDIUM","LOW"]
for rect in (pygame.Rect(510,150,75,52), pygame.Rect(450,250,68,40), pygame.Rect(450,370,68,48)):
    risk = risks[random.randint(0,2)]
    GeoFence(rect, risk, all_sprites, fences)
```

This code does not fail, but the titles are not displayed anywhere on the screen.

Comment: What should happen if the text is larger than the surface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're blitting the text at the coordinates `(200, 100)` of the `screen` surface when the sprites are created, so the text will disappear when the screen gets cleared in the next frame.

In order to blit the text on the `GeoFence` objects, you need to blit it onto the `self.image` at the coordinates `(0, 0)` (if it should be top left aligned).

If the surface should fit to the size of the text, you can render the text surface first and use its size as the size of the `self.image` surface.

```
import random
import pygame


pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
BG_COLOR = pygame.Color('gray12')
GREEN = pygame.Color('green')
FONT = pygame.font.SysFont('Arial', 25)


class GeoFence(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, rect, risk_level, *groups):
        self._layer = 1
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, groups)
        text_surface = FONT.render(risk_level, True, (255,0,0))
        self.image = pygame.surface.Surface(text_surface.get_size())
        self.image.fill(GREEN)
        self.image.blit(text_surface, (0, 0))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft=rect.topleft)
        self.risk_level = risk_level


all_sprites = pygame.sprite.LayeredUpdates()
fences = pygame.sprite.Group()

risks = ["HIGH","MEDIUM","LOW"]
for rect in (pygame.Rect(510,150,75,52), pygame.Rect(450,250,68,40),
             pygame.Rect(450,370,68,48)):
    risk = random.choice(risks)
    GeoFence(rect, risk, all_sprites, fences)

done = False
while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True

    all_sprites.update()

    screen.fill(BG_COLOR)
    all_sprites.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)
```

It's also possible to pass another color to [`Font.render`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/font.html#pygame.font.Font.render) which will be used as the background color. That would allow you to shorten the code a little bit:

```
class GeoFence(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, rect, risk_level, *groups):
        self._layer = 1
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, groups)
        self.image = FONT.render(risk_level, True, (255,0,0), GREEN)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft=rect.topleft)
        self.risk_level = risk_level
```

If you want to center the text, create another rect for the text, set its `center` coords to the `self.rect.center` and then use it as the blit position for the text. The `self.rect` should still be at the default position (0, 0) when you do this.

```
def __init__(self, rect, risk_level, *groups):
    self._layer = 1
    pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, groups)
    text_surface = FONT.render(risk_level, True, (255,0,0))
    self.image = pygame.surface.Surface(
        (text_surface.get_width()+110, text_surface.get_height()+20))
    self.image.fill(GREEN)
    # Create the rect, but don't set the coordinates yet.
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    # Set the center of the text_rect to the center of the self.rect.
    text_rect = text_surface.get_rect(center=self.rect.center)
    # Then blit the text at the text_rect and it will be centered.
    self.image.blit(text_surface, text_rect)
    # Afterwards set the rect to the desired position.
    self.rect.topleft = rect.topleft
```